# Encoding class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I have searched all over for two hours and haven't been able to find an answer to my problem so if this question is answered somewhere else I apologize. I have found similar answers but none of them have worked. I am trying to encode / decode a custom class. I am new to iOS programming and am not sure why my images are not encoding / decoding. Everything works fine except for the images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. All I want is to be able to encode and save the images.

```
class NewCell: NSObject, NSCoding {


// MARK: Properties

var name: String

var category: String

var offerDescription: String

var webPage: String

var detailImage: UIImage!

var scrollImage: UIImage!

var homeImage: UIImage!

var discountValue: Double

var priceIcon: String

var arrowImage: UIImage!


// Mark: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("recentCells")


//MARK: Initialization

init?(name: String, category: String, offerDescription: String, webPage: String, detailImage: UIImage!, scrollImage: UIImage!, homeImage: UIImage!, discountValue: Double, priceIcon: String, arrowImage: UIImage!){

    // Initialize stored properties
    self.name = name
    self.category = category
    self.offerDescription = offerDescription
    self.webPage = webPage
    self.detailImage = detailImage
    self.scrollImage = scrollImage
    self.homeImage = homeImage
    self.discountValue = discountValue
    self.priceIcon = priceIcon
    self.arrowImage = arrowImage


    super.init()

    // Initialization should fail if any values are left blank

    if name.isEmpty || category.isEmpty || offerDescription.isEmpty

        || webPage.isEmpty || discountValue.isZero || priceIcon.isEmpty  {


        return nil

    }


}

// MARK: Properties

struct ProertyKey {

    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let categoryKey = "category"
    static let offerDescriptionKey = "offerDescription"
    static let webPageKey = "webPage"
    static let detailImageKey = "detailImage"
    static let scrollImageKey = "scrollImage"
    static let homeImageKey = "homeImage"
    static let discountValueKey = "discountValue"
    static let priceIconKey = "priceIcon"
    static let arrowImageKey = "arrowImage"

}




// MARK: NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {



    coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: ProertyKey.nameKey)
    coder.encodeObject(category, forKey: ProertyKey.categoryKey)
    coder.encodeObject(offerDescription, forKey: ProertyKey.offerDescriptionKey)
    coder.encodeObject(webPage, forKey: ProertyKey.webPageKey)
    coder.encodeObject(detailImage, forKey: ProertyKey.detailImageKey)
    coder.encodeObject(scrollImage, forKey: ProertyKey.scrollImageKey)
    coder.encodeObject(homeImage, forKey: ProertyKey.homeImageKey)
    coder.encodeObject(discountValue, forKey: ProertyKey.discountValueKey)
    coder.encodeObject(priceIcon, forKey: ProertyKey.priceIconKey)
    coder.encodeObject(arrowImage, forKey: ProertyKey.arrowImageKey)






}

required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

    let name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    let category = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("category") as! String
    let offerDescription = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("offerDescription") as! String
    let webPage = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("webPage") as! String
    let detailImage = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("detailImage") as? UIImage
    let scrollImage = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("scrollImage") as? UIImage
    let homeImage = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("homeImage") as? UIImage
    let discountValue = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("discountValue") as? Double
    let priceIcon = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("priceIcon") as! String
    let arrowImage = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("arrowImage") as? UIImage

    print(homeImage)

    // Must call designated initializer
    self.init(name: name, category: category, offerDescription: offerDescription, webPage: webPage, detailImage: detailImage, scrollImage:  scrollImage, homeImage:  homeImage, discountValue: discountValue!, priceIcon:  priceIcon, arrowImage:  arrowImage)

}
}
```

Comment: these `forKey:` in `encodeWithCoder ` should be `ProertyKey.nameKey.rawValue` i think

Comment: Try converting the image to data and save that data instead of the image, when decoding get it as data and convert it to an image.

Comment: In most cases it's not necessary to save image data. If the image is accessible by an URL save that URL or if the image is in the bundle save the name.